# Native Android java methods not finding any reference

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java-native-interface, android-native-library

I have Two Modules first have Jni Android.MK file and the second have CMakeList.txt
the first module has dependencies of the second module.
Now when I call any native java method from First Module it finding that method in the second module and says **

> No implementation found for "method name"

**

[image]

[image]
any solution or any suggestion pls.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Gonna need a lot more info than that...

Comment: @spartygw pls check.

Comment: Is `No implementation found` in logcat? Can you share a few lines above and below thta in the log?

Comment: Thank you @spartygw but I solve the problem. I really appreciate that you take my problem seriously try to help.